# Syntax derived classes/stuctures in c++

Tags: c++, vector, derived-class

I was tinkering around with a C++ project where I found a code snippet which is similar to one below.
I am not visualise/understand what exatly is going on here. I assume a vector of stucture pointers are being created, although I am not sure. Also I was trying to understand if there are other usecases where something like this is necessary to be defined? Could anyone help?

```
class Thread{
    ...
};
struct Threadpool : public std::vector<Thread*>{
    ...
};

Threadpool Threads;
```

Comment: Note that `std::vector` isn't really designed to be inherited from, for example it doesn't have a virtual destructor. You could use *private* inheritance, which makes it more of a "has a" relation instead and then it's better to not inherit at all and instead have a private member variable of the type.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet creates a vector which has Thread pointer as elements. You need to manage to allocate/deallocate the resources of the Threadpool instance. I think `public std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Thread>>` is safer